# error: Not All Code Paths Return A value?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I am Getting this Error (Not All Code Paths Return A Value). I want to insert data in my database with unique key constraint. but when i added this in my code my method is giving me this error.

Here is my code

```
  public string Insert()
    {

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ZARAK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectDAL;integrated security=true");


        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO tbl_User(Name,Email,Password) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + password + "')", Conn);


            int restl = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //temp = true;
            return "Record Inserted successfully!";
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {
                 return "Record Already Exists";
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: your exception doesn´t return a value in every case.

Comment: return a string in finally block.

Comment: if you get an exception, and the exception number is not 2627, what is your method going to return?

Comment: What if you get exception before return in try block or ex.Number is not 2627? returning some value just before the end of method will remove the error.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is here:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2627)
    {
        return "Record Already Exists";
    }
    // **
}
```

If you look at the code paths of your application, each `if` also implicitly adds an `else`. In this case the `else` doesn't contain a `return` statement, hence the error.

**And then there's exceptions...**

Exceptions are there to handle exceptional cases. There's this implicit agreement amongst software developers that `catch` implies *handle it appropriately*.

One way to handle it is to inform the user that the record already exists (I'm guessing that's what you do). If another thing happens, it's not always productive to inform the user of the error; you might simply want to try again in a few seconds (deadlock) or do something else. Usually you handle code like that on a higher level, and let the exception ripple.

As a result, I cannot tell you what the code of ** needs to be; you need to decide that for yourself based on what you want to achieve.

For example:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2627)
    {
        return "Record Already Exists"; // user needs to do something
    }

    // We don't want to handle the rest here:
    throw;
}
```

Comment: so i have to add an else statement?

Comment: @ZarakDawood, Yes, or just a `return "Exception ocurred";` outside the `if` block.

Comment: Or don't return a string, and let the `Exception` throw. In this case you're not really handling the `Exception`; since you're not, I also wouldn't pretend to have handled it by returning a string.

Comment: In the case where the SqlException Number is not `2627` might want to just rethrow the exception, eg. `throw ex;` instead of returning a string..

Comment: @ColinZabransky Yea that's what I wrote a moment ago :-) More importantly: don't do `throw ex;` ; use `throw;`. Otherwise you will loose information.

Comment: @atlaste I assumed it's what you meant, just making it explicit for the asker. Good call on `throw` vs. `throw ex`.

Comment: I want the user to receive an error when he will try to insert email more than once. I have a unique key constraint is added for email but it is not working? what should I have to do ?

Comment: Compiler is not Reading the SqlException?

Answer (score 2):

In your code The possible code paths are

1. `=>Try=>finally=> Exit`
2. `=>catch=>ex.Number == 2627=>finally=>Exit`
3. `=>catch=>ex.Number != 2627=>finally=>Exit`

Through your code you have handled the first two; The compiler will not know what to do if he met with the third Condition that's why it showing such error. 
This can be solved by treating the third code path(`ex.Number != 2627`).  Now consider the following code:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2627)
    {
        return "Record Already Exists";
    }
    return "Some other error occurred";
}
```

> One more thing you have to notice is the Plain Text queries. Which
>   will opens a wide door for SQL Injection. So i request you to use
>   [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx).

Including all these changes, the Method signature for the `Insert()` will be like the following:

```
public string Insert()
{
    // Assuming Name email and passwords are global variables
    // Or else need to get them
    string conStr = @"Data Source=ZARAK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectDAL;integrated security=true";
    int queryResult = 0;
    try
    {
        string querySQL = "Insert INTO tbl_User(Name,Email,Password)VALUES(@name,@email,@password)";
        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querySQL, Conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
               queryResult= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return queryResult + "Record/s Inserted successfully!";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
            return "Record Already Exists";
        }
        return "Some other error";
    }           
}
```

Comment: I want the user to receive an error when he will try to insert email more than one. I have a unique key constraint is added for email but it is not working? what should I have to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Alter your code into this to make sure that you have a return value.

```
public string Insert()
{
    var result = String.Empty;
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ZARAK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjectDAL;integrated security=true");


    try
    {
        Conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO tbl_User(Name,Email,Password) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + password + "')", Conn);


        int restl = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //temp = true;
        result =  "Record Inserted successfully!";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
             result = "Record Already Exists";
        }
        else {
            result = ex.Message; // For other exceptions
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Conn.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you must return a string in all execution paths.

```
public string SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        //Path 1
        return "Path 1";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (...) {
             //Path 2
             return "Path 2";              
        }

       //Path 3
       //Return or rethrow.
       //return "Path 3";
       throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        //Clean Up Resources
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application throw an Exception and the Exception number is not equals to 2627, your method will not return a string value.

```
        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO tbl_User(Name,Email,Password) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + password + "')", Conn);


            int restl = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //temp = true;
            return "Record Inserted successfully!";
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {
                return "Record Already Exists";
            }
            return "Your Text";
        }
        finally
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
        return "Your Text";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In additional to *atlaste*'s nice answer. In case of *C# 6.0* in order to avoid such errors and simplify `try .. catch` block you can put *exception filter*:

```
  try {
    ...
  }
  catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 2627) {
    return "Record Already Exists";
  }
```

no `if`, no `throw;`